# Set the temporary table in SQL server as variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a temporary table but I need to change the name of the table based on the content of a variable as I need to create more than one table inside a while loop. Is there a way to do that?

```
while(@roCounter <= @insideCounter)
     BEGIN
     set @nameOfTable = @nameOfTable+@roCounter
     select * into #@nameOfTable from #CC where ro=@roCounter --@nameOfTable is a variable
     set @roCounter = @roCounter +1
    END
     Drop Table #CC
    set @counter = @counter +1
END
```

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the solution here.

Comment: Or you could *not* create separate tables, but instead add a column to distinguish the data, and a suitable index. In fact you seem to already have that, but then want to split it into physical tables again. If this is done to appease something further down the line, consider rewriting *that*. Otherwise, look into table partitioning and/or partitioned views as ways to do this with fewer headaches.

Comment: This certainly seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What is the *real* problem you're trying to solve here.